# Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter: one as a library, in the other users can add their own security access

Tags: spring, spring-security, stormpath

I am creating a Spring Security configuration to be used as a library by any developer who wants to create a Stormpath Spring application secured by Spring Security.

For that I have sub-classed `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and defined the Stormpath Access Controls in `configure(HttpSecurity)` as well as the Stormpath `AuthenticationProvider` by means of `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`. All this can be seen in this abstract class and its concrete sub-class:

```java
@Order(99)
public abstract class AbstractStormpathWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Removed properties and beans for the sake of keeping focus on the important stuff

    /**
     * The pre-defined Stormpath access control settings are defined here.
     *
     * @param http the {@link HttpSecurity} to be modified
     * @throws Exception if an error occurs
     */
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, LogoutHandler logoutHandler)
            throws Exception {

        if (loginEnabled) {
            http
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage(loginUri)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl(loginNextUri)
                    .successHandler(successHandler)
                    .usernameParameter("login")
                    .passwordParameter("password");
        }

        if (logoutEnabled) {
            http
                    .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl(logoutUri)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutNextUri)
                    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler);

        }

        if (!csrfProtectionEnabled) {
            http.csrf().disable();
        } else {
            //Let's configure HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository to play nicely with our Controllers' forms
            http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(stormpathCsrfTokenRepository());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to specify the {@link AuthenticationProvider} that Spring Security will use when processing authentications.
     *
     * @param auth the {@link AuthenticationManagerBuilder} to use
     * @param authenticationProvider the {@link AuthenticationProvider} to whom Spring Security will delegate authentication attempts
     * @throws Exception if an error occurs
     */
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class StormpathWebSecurityConfiguration extends AbstractStormpathWebSecurityConfiguration {

    //Removed beans for the sake of keeping focus on the important stuff

    @Override
    protected final void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        configure(http, stormpathAuthenticationSuccessHandler(), stormpathLogoutHandler());
    }

    @Override
    protected final void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        configure(auth, super.stormpathAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

In short, we are basically defining our login and logout mechanisms and integrating our CSRF code to play nicely with Spring Security's one.

Up to this point everything works OK.

But this is just the "library" and we want users to build their own applications on top of it.

So, we have created a Sample application to demonstrate how a user will use our library.

Basically users will want to create their own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Like this:

```java
@EnableStormpathWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Order(1)
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated();
    }

}
```

In case this is actually needed, the `WebApplicationInitializer` looks like this:

```java
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(SpringSecurityWebAppConfig.class);
        context.register(StormpathMethodSecurityConfiguration.class);
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        //Stormpath Filter
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = sc.addFilter("stormpathFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> types =
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(types, false, "/*");

        //Spring Security Filter
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilter = sc.addFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME, DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        securityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
    }
}
```

All this code boots up correctly. If I go to `localhost:8080` I see the welcome screen. If I go to `localhost:8080/login` I see the login screen. But, if I go to `localhost:8080/restricted` I should be redirected to the login page since we have this line: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated();`. However I am seeing the `Access Denied` page instead.

Then, if I add the login url in the App's access control, like this:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated();
}
```

It now redirects me to the login page but as soon as I submit the credentials I get an CSRF problem meaning that all our configuration is not actually part of this filter chain.

When I debug it all it seems that each `WebApplicationInitializer` is having its own instance with its own Filter Chain. I would expect them to be concatenated somehow but it seems that it is not actually happening...

Anyone has ever tried something like this?

BTW: As a workaround users can do `public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends StormpathWebSecurityConfiguration` instead of `SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. This way it works but I want users to have pure Spring Security code and extending from our `StormpathWebSecurityConfiguration` diverges from that goal.

All the code can be seen [here](https://github.com/mrioan/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/spring_security_extension_redirect_to_login_not_working). The Stormpath Spring Security library for Spring is under `extensions/spring/stormpath-spring-security-webmvc`. The Sample App using the library is under `examples/spring-security-webmvc`.

It is very simple to run... You just need to register to Stormpath [as explained here](http://docs.stormpath.com/rest/quickstart/#get-an-api-key). Then you can checkout the `spring_security_extension_redirect_to_login_not_working` branch and start the sample app like this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:mrioan/stormpath-sdk-java.git
$ git checkout spring_security_extension_redirect_to_login_not_working
$ mvn install -DskipTests=true
$ cd examples/spring-security-webmvc
$ mvn jetty:run
```

Then you can go to `localhost:8080/restricted` to see that you are not being redirected to the login page.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience there are issues with having multiple `WebSecurityConfigurer`s messing with the security configuration on startup.

The best way to solve this is to make your library configuration into `SecurityConfigurerAdapters` that can be applied where appropriate.

```
public class StormpathHttpSecurityConfigurer
        extends AbstractStormpathWebSecurityConfiguration
        implements SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    //Removed beans for the sake of keeping focus on the important stuff

    @Override
    protected final void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        configure(http, stormpathAuthenticationSuccessHandler(), stormpathLogoutHandler());
    }
}

public class StormpathAuthenticationManagerConfigurer
        extends AbstractStormpathWebSecurityConfiguration
        implements SecurityConfigurer<AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationManagerBuilder> {

    //Removed beans for the sake of keeping focus on the important stuff

    @Override
    protected final void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        configure(auth, super.stormpathAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

You then have your users `apply` these in their own configuration:

```
@EnableStormpathWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Order(1)
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .apply(new StormPathHttpSecurityConfigurer(...))
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.apply(new StormPathAuthenticationManagerConfigurer(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually the way we finally implemented that. To make since cleaner we imported the configurer statically. Things finally look like this: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/spring-security-spring-boot-webmvc-bare-bones/src/main/java/com/stormpath/spring/boot/examples/SpringSecurityWebAppConfig.java

Comment: Linked file has changed. New one: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/spring-security-webmvc/src/main/java/com/stormpath/spring/examples/SpringSecurityWebAppConfig.java

Comment: This solution no longer works because `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implements `SecurityConfigurer<Filter, T>` so we cannot make our own `SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>`. A shame too, because I am trying to do something very similar.

Answer (score -2):

It's definitely the problem regarding either order of your Antmatchers or hasn't specified ROLES of users that you permit to access the URL.

What do you have anything above "/restricted"?

Is something completely blocking anything below that URL? You should specify more specific URLS first then, generalised URLs.

Try configuring above URL properly (or tell me what it is so I can help you out), perhaps apply "fullyAuthenticated" also "permitAll" ROLEs on the parent URL of "/restricted".

Comment: It is not just a matter of ordering. If I do this: 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated();
    }

Then I get redirected but I stumbled into a CSRF problem (already working propelry in the configuration in `AbstractStormpathWebSecurityConfiguration`). It seems there are 2 independent chain filters playing here which are not properly being concatenated.

Comment: You essentially have a chain of security filters, that are in order anyway. If you are facing CSRF problem, then your users are not properly authenticated yet, before hitting that URL. Otherwise, if the URL doesn't require any means of Authentication, just disable CSRF by .csrf().disable.